# Link to a specific div in another app(page) in Django using anchor tag

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls, django-1.10

I have a div with a certain id

```
<div id="services">
```

Then I try to link to it using Django templates

```
<a href="{% url 'homepage' %}#services">
```

But it only works if I'm in the same page (App) 
Is there a way to work around this ?

Comment: this should work. can you verify that the URL in the address bar is actually proper rendered, like www.yourpage.com/site#services ?

Comment: Thank you, I found out what the problem was.
I had a script that does smooth scrolling and it had "   event.preventDefault();" in it. as I removed that it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. I had a script that does smooth scrolling and it had "event.preventDefault();" in it. as I removed that it worked.